# to write case when to another case when in one select Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a new user in Google Big Query and I want to write two "Case when...." in one select, and they should be connected to each other

For example:

`Case when number = 1 then 'one' when number=2 then 'two' else 'other' end as mark`

`Case when mark = 'one' then 'red' when mark='two' then 'orange' else 'other' end as color`

But I have mistake like 'Unrecognized name: mark at [8:14]'

I used all the options with apostrophe but still have the same result.

I also try to find answer in BigQuery Documentation but it was unsuccessfully.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: SQL does not allow column expressions to refer to other column aliases in the same level, so you will need to use an outer-query. Yes, it's dumb, blame the ISO SQL committee for creating such a painful language.

Comment: @Dai, thank you! I thought so but I just wanted to hear something else :)

Comment: As an alternative to an outer-query, you could use a CTE. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're [using Google BigQuery's current SQL syntax support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax), as opposed to their older SQL implementation.

SQL does not allow column expressions to refer to other column aliases in the same level, so you will need to use an outer-query. <sub>Yes, it's dumb, blame the ISO SQL committee for creating such a terribly unergonomic language.</sub>

You'll want something like this:

- I'm not a BigQuery user so I don't know if this syntax is fully supported, but I believe the query below is ISO SQL-compliant).
- Note the use of `CASE <expr> WHEN <value>` instead of `CASE WHEN <expr> = <value>` btw.

```
SELECT
    t.*
    t.number,

    CASE t.mark
        WHEN 'one' THEN 'red'
        WHEN 'two' THEN 'orange' ELSE 'other'
    END AS color
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            y.*,
            CASE y.number
                WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'other'
            END AS mark
        FROM
            someTable AS y
    ) AS t
```

---

Another alternative is to use a CTE, which is essentially the same as the above but the inner-query is expressed *above* the outer-query instead of *inside* it (and it can be reused more easily in the same query):

```
WITH t AS (
    
    SELECT
        y.*,
        CASE y.number
            WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'other'
        END AS mark
    FROM
        someTable AS y
)
SELECT
    t.*
    t.number,

    CASE t.mark
        WHEN 'one' THEN 'red'
        WHEN 'two' THEN 'orange' ELSE 'other'
    END AS color
FROM
    t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below option (BigQuery)

```
select *, 
  Case mark when 'one' then 'red' when 'two' then 'orange' else 'other' end as color
from data, unnest([
  struct(Case number when 1 then 'one' when 2 then 'two' else 'other' end as mark)
])
```

Obviously this is a matter of preferences, but in my practice, I am using above approach much more frequently than subquery and/or cte

You can test it using dummy data as in below example

```
with data as (
  select 1 number union all 
  select 2 union all 
  select 3
)
select *, 
  Case mark when 'one' then 'red' when 'two' then 'orange' else 'other' end as color
from data, unnest([
  struct(Case number when 1 then 'one' when 2 then 'two' else 'other' end as mark)
])
```

with output

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer
I've just red about UNNEST and it was very useful info for my future tasks!